# Error : "Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in"

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-4.3.1\wp-includes\query.php on line 3716

I don't know what is this I am searching from internet but not find the solution

Comment: what are you trying to do? If you are using WP_QUERY you'll get an object which you have to treat like an object and not like an array (e.g. not $query['val'] but $query->val)

Comment: No I am no using wp query I use simple wordpress while loop to shoe posts

Answer (score 2):

This error is telling you that a post object has been passed into a function or method where an array was expected. The file you cited is the location there whe error was reported. Use a stack trace to determine where the error originated from to solve your problem.

Comment: Oky lets i try it